# How to mimic the "Install Ubuntu" application inside a full installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: 14.04, system-installation, live-usb

I currently have a full installation of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on a 8GB USB drive (not a live USB, a full install). Which package do I install to mimic the "Install Ubuntu" application on the desktop of a live USB?

I realize it might be nearly 1GB in size, since it has to contain the whole installation media, but I'm perfectly fine with that.

Basically I'm looking for a way to plug my 8GB full installation USB drive into a new computer, double click the "Install Ubuntu" icon on the desktop, and then be able to follow the graphic installation wizard just like a regular Ubuntu install disc.

Comment: I doubt you can, it's not meant to install that way; you could try qemu + an .iso perhaps? Obviously you can't just transplant your installation as the hardware will differ - if it doesn't, you could use a compressed disk image & `cat`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out it's as easy as:

`sudo apt-get install ubiquity ubiquity-frontend-gtk`

Then `ubiquity gtk_ui` will bring up the exact same installer as the one from the Live USB.

Or alternatively you can copy the `ubiquity.desktop` file from the desktop of the Live USB if you want a nice GUI way of launching the installer.